# Assertion Failed: Expected the primary data returned by the serializer for a `queryRecord` response to be a single object but instead it was an array

Tags: ember-data

I have just got this error a few days ago. Whenever I try to run

```
this.store.queryRecord('user', {filter:{username : params.username}});
```

It shows error: Assertion Failed: Expected the primary data returned by the serializer for a `queryRecord` response to be a single object but instead it was an array.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to avoid this problem. Instead of queryRecord ( which seems to be changed by ember-data developer team ), I use store.query like this:

```
this.store.query('user', {filter:{username : params.username}}).then(function(user){return user.get('firstObject')});
```

Answer (score 0):

You backend should return one object not array.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar situation , had 2 routes

```
this.get('/clients', function() {return {data: [allClientsDataJson]};});
this.get('/clients:id', function() {return {data: [oneClientDataJson]};});
```

But after using queryRecord i got same error. Thing was that second route was never called and first one was called in both causes. So instead of single result there was array with all results in second call.

After knowing only first one is always called i edited it to :

```
    this.get('/clients', function(db, request) {
    if(!Ember.isEmpty(request.queryParams)) { return oneClientDataJson 
    } else { return allClientsDataJson }
```